# Searching a binary tree then updating repetition counts

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

i am writing a program that reads a file from stdin. The file has different names on several lines and I am trying to avoid repeated names being entered into the binary tree. I wrote some code just to make sure im adding the names to the nodes and printing all names in the input file. I was able to successfully do that but now im trying to go back and avoid entering a name twice,but update the count if the name is found more then once. So i am confused on how to search this binary tree and at what point to search, do i search as i get each name from the file? the commented portion of this code is what im thinking of implementing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char* name;
    int count;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* addNode(char* string);
/*struct node* search(struct node* root, char* stringg);*/
void insert(struct node *root, char* stringgg);
void preorder(struct node *root);

int main()
{
    char buffer[20];
    struct node *root = NULL;

    while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL )
    {
        count = 0;

        if(root == NULL)
            root = addNode(buffer,&count);
        else
          /*root = search(root,buffer) is this correct here? search for the name as it comes in, if found in search root changes to place where it was found*/
        insert(root,buffer);

    }
    preorder(root);

}

struct node* addNode(char* string,int *countptr)
{
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->name = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    strcpy(temp->name,string);
    temp->count = *count + 1;

    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

/*struct node* search(struct node* root, char* stringg);*/
  {
       if(strcmp(root->name,stringg) == 0);/*if found, return adress of where it was found*/
       return root;
       /*unsure of other conditions to test for and what to change how do i check the left and right side and recursivly check until the whole tree is searched? */

  }

void insert(struct node *root, char* stringgg)
{
    if(strcmp(stringgg,root->name) < 0)
    {
        if(root->left == NULL)
            root->left = addNode(stringgg);
        else
            insert(root->left, stringgg);
    }
    else
    {
        if(root->right == NULL)
            root->right = addNode(stringgg);
        else
            insert(root->right,stringgg);
    }
}

void preorder(struct node *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%s",root->name);
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);

}
```

i would like it so by the time i print these nodes, i get no repeated names, but a count of how many times the name was repeated in the file. SO if i have file being read by std in form

```
bob
john
dylan 
bob
dylan 
dylan
```

when im done building the tree and printing the general form will be

```
bob 2
dylan 3
john 1
```

Comment: `addNode` used two interface.

Comment: can you explain a bit? Sorry didnt catch what you said.

Comment: prototype : `struct node* addNode(char* string);`, implement : `struct node* addNode(char* string,int *countptr){ ...` , used :  `root = addNode(buffer,&count);` , `root->left = addNode(stringgg);`...

Answer (score 0):

Just have your insert function deal with the `== 0` case by incrementing the node count rather than adding a new node.  (You already handle `> 0` and `< 0`, just add the last case.)

Comment: so inside the insert function i should call the search function?

Comment: @ZachSantiago No.  The insert function already traverses the tree to the insert point.  If that insert point already contains a node with the new value, don't insert a new one. Just increment the count in the node.